# Is Swift done type-check multiple times when building

Tags: swift, optimization, build-time

I'm currently working on build time optimization. I added these 2 lines to the 'Other swift flags' debug option.

After a clean building of the project, I saw some lines give warnings multiple times. Are these warnings coming from type-checking multiple times?

If I just add `: UIColor` after the definition, is it solves?

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=50
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=50
```

[image]

Comment: Does it show multiple times if you clean and build again?

Comment: Yes, I built multiple times still has multiple warnings @EmilioPelaez, I guess codes like `backgroundColor = .white` cause these warnings.